# Actionscript3 button tip

Tags: actionscript-3

Please, someone could help me?

I need to send the parameter **ad_mc** by the command:

```
ad_btn.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, MouseOver);
```

to use the same function for all buttons

```
function MouseOver(evt:MouseEvent):void{
 ad_mc.gotoAndPlay("on");
}

function MouseOut(evt:MouseEvent):void{
 ad_mc.gotoAndPlay("off");
}

ad_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, MouseOut);
ad_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, MouseOver);
```

If I wanted to send the parameter **ad_btn** I would use:

```
MovieClip (evt.target). GotoAndPlay ("on");
```

but is not the case

Comment: I don't understand the question, but perhaps your call to GotoAndPlay("on") is the problem? It should be "gotoAndPlay("on"), not GotoAndPlay("on")... good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ad_mc` is a child of `ad_btn` or if `ad_mc` is listening for mouse events that are bubbling up then you could try using `evt.currentTarget` otherwise you'll need to do something like this:

```
function MouseOver(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (evt.target == ad_btn) {
        ad_mc.gotoAndPlay("on");
    }
}

function MouseOut(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (evt.target == ad_btn) {
        ad_mc.gotoAndPlay("off");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using evt.currentTarget